# Mock property return value gets overridden when instantiating mock object

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock

### Background

I'm trying to set up a test fixture for an application I'm writing in which one of my classes is replaced with a mock. I'm happy to leave most of the attributes of the mock class as the default `MagicMock` instances (where I'm only interested in making assertions about their usage), but the class also has a property that I want to provide a specific return value for.

For reference, this is the outline of the class I'm trying to patch:

```
class CommunicationService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__received_response = Subject()

    @property
    def received_response(self):
        return self.__received_response

    def establish_communication(self, hostname: str, port: int) -> None:
        pass

    def send_request(self, request: str) -> None:
        pass
```

### Problem

The difficulty I'm having is that when I patch `CommunicationService`, I also try to set a `PropertyMock` for the `received_response` attribute that will return a specific value. When I instantiate this class in my production code, however, I'm finding that calls to `CommunicationService.received_response` are returning the default `MagicMock` instances instead of the specific value I want them to return.

During test setup, I do the following:

```
context.mock_comms_exit_stack = ExitStack()
context.mock_comms = context.mock_comms_exit_stack.enter_context(
    patch('testcube.comms.CommunicationService', spec=True))

# Make 'received_response' observers subscribe to a mock subject.
context.mock_received_response_subject = Subject()
type(context.mock_comms).received_response = PropertyMock(return_value=context.mock_received_response_subject)

# Reload TestCube module to make it import the mock communications class.
reload_testcube_module(context)
```

In my production code (invoked after performing this setup):

```
# Establish communication with TestCube Web Service.
comms = CommunicationService()
comms.establish_communication(hostname, port)

# Wire plugins with communications service.
for plugin in context.command.plugins:
    plugin.on_response = comms.received_response
    plugin.request_generated.subscribe(comms.send_request)
```

I expect `comms.received_response` to be an instance of `Subject` (the return value of the property mock). However, instead I get the following:

```
<MagicMock name='CommunicationService().received_response' id='4580209944'>
```

The problem seems to be that the mock property on the instance returned from the patch method works fine, but *mock properties get messed up when creating a new instance of the patched class*.

### SSCCE

I believe that the snippet below captures the essence of this problem. If there's a way to modify the script below to make it so that `print(foo.bar)` returns `mock value`, then hopefully it'll show how I can resolve the problem in my actual code.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock

class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 'real value'

exit_stack = ExitStack()
mock_foo = exit_stack.enter_context(patch('__main__.Foo', spec=True))
mock_bar = PropertyMock(return_value='mock value')
type(mock_foo).bar = mock_bar

print(mock_foo.bar) # 'mock value' (expected)

foo = Foo()
print(foo.bar) # <MagicMock name='Foo().bar' id='4372262080'> (unexpected - should be 'mock value')

exit_stack.close()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following line:

```
type(mock_foo).bar = mock_bar
```

mocks `mock_foo` which, at that point, is the return value of `enter_context`. If I understand [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack.enter_context) correctly it means you're now actually handling the result of `__enter__` of the return value of `patch('__main__.Foo', spec=True)`.

If you change that line to:

```
type(Foo.return_value).bar = mock_bar
```

then you'll mock the property `bar` of instances of `Foo` (as the return value of calling a class is an instance). The second print statement will then print `mock value` as expected.

Comment: Cheers mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but was my solution to a simpler problem, having learned from Simeon's answer.

In my case I wanted to mock `obj.my_method().my_property` and was getting `PropertyMock` as the return, as I was setting my return value's property directly to my `PropertyMock` instance, instead of the `type` of the mock returned by the method. This was the fixed code:

```
with patch.object(MyObj, "my_method") as method_mock:
    property_mock = PropertyMock(return_value='foo')
    type(method_mock.return_value).my_property = property_mock
```